# Going down columns using xlrd

Tags: python, loops, xlrd

Let's say I have a cell (9,3). I want to get the values from (9,3) to (9,99). How do I go down the columns to get the values. I am trying to write the values into another excel file that starts from (13, 3) and ends at (13,99).  How do I write a loop for that in xlrd?

```
def write_into_cols_rows(r, c):
    for num in range (0,96):
        c += 1
    return (r,c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`worksheet.row(int)` will return you the row, and to get the value of certain columns, you need to run `row[int].value` to get the value.

For more information, you can read [this](http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf) pdf file (Page 9 Introspecting a sheet).

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
# This will get you the very first sheet in the workbook.
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(workbook.sheet_names()[0])
for index in range(worksheet.nrows):
    try:
        row = worksheet.row(index)
        row_value = [col.value for col in row]
        # now row_value is a list contains all the column values
        print row_value[3:99]
    except:
        pass
```

To write data to Excel file, you might want to check out `xlwt` package.

BTW, seems like you are doing something like reading from excel.. do some work... write to excel... 
I would also recommend you take a look at `numpy`, `scipy` or `R`. When I usually do data munging, I use `R`  and it saves me so much time.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your help!! That pdf looks very useful. I have one more question though, how do write/or get each value. Your program seems to print all the values at once in one quick succession.

Comment: @user3078335, seems like you are not that familiar with Python syntax.. in my code, there is a `print` command, which will print the 3rd to 99th elements to the screen as you mentioned in your question... you can change that to whatever column you want. The to write to Excel, go to page 22.

Comment: ha! yeah.. i am still new to python. Used to programming in java and c++, python syntax is kinda different. Got it. Thanks!!